# Python + CSV : How can I create a new csv and write new columns to that in Python?

Tags: python, csv

I want to make a **new** CSV from scratch. In that CSV I'll store new cells row wise. Each cell value will be computed dynamically and row will be stored to the csv in a loop. Unfortunately, all of the available codes for this purpose are for already existing CSVs. **A code without using Pandas dataframe will be preferred.**

Final CSV should look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have data coming in as a list ,

```
import csv

list_1 = ['UOM','BelRd(D2)','Ulsoor(D2)','Chrch(D2)','BlrClub(D2)','Indrangr(D1)','Krmngl(D1','KrmnglBkry(D1)']
list_2 = ['PKT',0,0,0,0,0,0,1]

with open('/path/filename.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(list_1)
    writer.writerow(list_2)
```

Comment: Each cell value will be computed dynamically and row will be stored to the csv in a loop. Can u modify your code for that?

Comment: @Debbie, you can append each cell value for a row to a list and write to a csv file.  change will be `with open('/path/filename.csv', 'a', newline='') as outfile:`, which will append lines to the end of file

Answer (score 1):

you can create your own csv file, here I would like to show you how you can create csv file with headers.

```
import csv
rowHeaders = ["Title", "Coupon code", "Description", "Image path", "Website link", "offer expire"]
fp = open('groupon_output.csv', 'w')
mycsv = csv.DictWriter(fp, fieldnames=rowHeaders)
#write header will write your desire header
mycsv.writeheader()

# you can write multiple value to take it inside the loop
#you can write row values using dict writer
title="testing"
coupon_code="xx"
description="nothing much"
image_path="not given"
current_page_url="www.google.com"

mycsv.writerow({"Title": title, "Coupon code": coupon_code, "Description": description,"Image path": image_path, "Website link": current_page_url,"offer expire": "Not Avialable"})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

data =  [
        [ 'a','b','c','d'],
        [ 'b','1','2','3'],
        [ 'c','4','5','6'],
        [ 'd','7','8','9'],
        ]

with open ('output.csv', 'w') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

This could help you!

```
def header():
    # Instead of hard coding like below, pass variables which hold dynamic values
    # This kind of hard coding can you help you when headers are fixed
    h1 = ['Date']  
    h2 = ['Feed']
    h3 = ['Status']
    h4 = ['Path']

    rows = zip(h1, h2, h3, h4)

    with open('test.txt', 'a') as f:
        wr = csv.writer(f)
        for row in rows:
            wr.writerow(row)
        f.close()
```